# How to populate date fields in an ASP.NET Core form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When editing a simple entity model class, the date field value does not pre-populate on the edit page. While all of the other fields on the edit page pre-populate with the entity values from the database, the date fields do not. I have checked in SQL Server, and also the details page confirms that the dates did save when the entity instance was created.

How can the date field be pre-populated in the edit form?

**Date field in entity model class**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]  
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]  
[Display(Name = "Example date")]  
public DateTime ExampleDate { get; set; }
```

**Date field in Edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Project.ExampleDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Project.ExampleDate" value="@Model.Project.ExampleDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Project.ExampleDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can try to change your `Edit.cshtml` like following.

```
  <input asp-for="@Model.Project.ExampleDate" value="@Model.Project.ExampleDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" class="form-control" />
```

**Solution 2:**

You can change your model class like following (delete code `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`):

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]  
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}")]  
[Display(Name = "Example date")]  
public DateTime ExampleDate { get; set; }
```